# A&H kishke - yoshon?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, food, yashan-chadash

Does anyone happen to know if [Abeles and Heymann frozen kishke](http://abeles-heymann.com/collections/specialty/products/a-h-beef-kishka) is [yoshon](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/yoshon/)? (It does not appear to be mentioned at all in Y. Herman's Guide to Chodosh.)  (Alternatively, does anyone know of a decent, sugar-free, yoshon [kishke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishka_(food))?

Comment: It's hard to imagine anyone here will have any more information than the Guide does. Your best (if not only) bet is probably emailing them and asking for codes.

Comment: @DoubleAA waiting to hear back

Comment: @Loewian I know this will soon be obsolete for this season, but the most recent version of the Guide does have something on A&H products. It lists a number to call on page 66.